# Sending GA for Firebase event via Measurement Protocol

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm using Google Analytics property for Firebase project, and I'm trying to send some event via Measurement Protocol but as far as I see there is no specific MP parameters for such events.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I am not sure i completely understand your question these are the MP event properties https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#events  Please edit your question and add the request that you are currently sending and what issues you are having with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to add an additional attribute to your GA data then a [custom variable or dimension/metric within GA](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829?hl=en) might be what you're after.

Once that's in place you should be able to populate it using the MP.

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.